# Remove meta badges

Tags: feature-request, meta, badges

Currently, we have the [Quorum](https://stackapps.com/help/badges/86/quorum) and [Convention](https://stackapps.com/help/badges/87/convention) badges even though Stack apps is its [own meta](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-meta) so they are unobtainable. I think they should be removed to make it so only obtainable badges are on the badge page. After all, MSE does not have meta-related badges.